# MIPS Playing beep sound

Tags: mips

Good Evening!

I want to make beep sound using MIPS system call 31 which simulates MIDI output sound. I specified all system call 31 needed parameters such as $a0 - pitch sound , $a1 - duration. But after execution the sound are not playing. Could you say what is not right. I have also added 12, to make pitches in ocatve. So I have made all what system call 31 requires to play sound. Thanks!

```
.text
.globl main

main:   



li $v0,31
la $a0,beep
addi $t2,$a0,12
la $a1,duration

move $t2,$a0
move $t3,$a1

syscall


.data

beep: .byte 72
duration: .byte 100
volume: .byte 127
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confusing `la` (load address) with `lw` load word. After `la $a0, beep` $a0 contains the address of beep, not its contents.

To fix this error:

```
li $v0,31
la $a0,beep
lw $a0 0($a0)
addi $t2,$a0,12
la $a1,duration
lw $a1, 0($a1)

move $t2,$a0
move $t3,$a1

syscall
```

Also, it looks like you have forgotten to load the volume into $a3, so it is probably 0.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have edit my code (loaded duration), but sound still not plays, the error on line 15, says that it is out of boundary: .text
.globl main

main:  


li $v0,31

la $t0,song

lw $a0,0($t0)

addi $t2,$a0,12
la $t1,duration
lw $a1,0($t1)

la $t3,volume
lw $a3,0($t3)



move $t4,$a0
move $t5,$a1
move $t6,$a3

syscall


.data

song: .byte 69
duration: .byte 10
volume: .byte 40

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are bytes (8 bits), but you're trying to loads words (32 bits). You can't load words from non-word aligned addresses, and even if you could you wouldn't be getting the right results.

So you need to change:

```
la $t0,song 
lw $a0,0($t0)
```

to

```
la $t0,song 
lbu $a0,0($t0)
```

and so on for the other loads.

---

I don't see you loading an instrument number into `$a2` anywhere.

---

You should end your program with a `jr $ra` instruction, otherwise the CPU will keep executing whatever happens to come after the `syscall` instruction.

---

`syscall` 31 is not blocking; it completes right away, so if you end your program immediately afterwards you probably won't hear the beep. You can use `syscall` 33 instead, which works the same as 31, except that it blocks for the duration of the tone.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks for it! I have added 4 song variables with Piano, Bass but melody too short, is it possible to increase duration more than 127. I know that maximum is 127 but any anyway it takes a lot of song word variables to make sound longer

Answer (score 0):

```
li $v0, 31 
la $t0, pitch
la $t1, duration 
la $t2, instrument
la $t3, volume 
move $a0, $t0 
move $a1, $t1 
move $a2, $t2
move $a3, $t3 
syscall 

############
### END ####
############
li $v0, 10 #end program
syscall

.data 
pitch: .byte 69 # Put the notes to your song in a MIPS “array”
duration: .byte 100
instrument: .byte 58
volume: .byte 100
```